# Custom Div slider is going too fast, but only when returning from another browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, browser-tab

When I am viewing the code in action, there are no problems. But as soon as I spend some time at another browser tab, then return to the code in action, the timing/speed is too fast.

Here's the jQuery:

```
var divId = 1;
var lp = 0;

$(document).ready(function (){

    setInterval(function()
        {
        //<![CDATA[

            if(divId < 6)
            {
                $('.main-banner').animate({ left: lp },400);

                $(".first-icon-inner").removeClass("active-icon");
                $("#banner-"+divId+" div:first").addClass('active-icon');

                    divId++;
                    lp-=550;

            }
            else
            {
                lp = 0;
                divId=1;

                $('.main-banner').animate({ left: lp },400);

                $(".first-icon-inner").removeClass("active-icon");
                $("#banner-"+divId+" div:first").addClass('active-icon');


            }
            //]]>

    }, 3400);

});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: Why do you have `//<![CDATA[` in the middle of your script? interesting...

Comment: @Alvin Wong, I used it for XHTML validator.

Comment: @ankit5607san because I usually only see them at start of the `<script>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug with jQuery < 1.6.3 ... extract from [jQuery 1.6.3 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/09/01/jquery-1-6-3-released/) :

> We had high hopes for the browser’s requestAnimationFrame API when we added support into version 1.6. However, one of the highest-volume complaints we’ve received since then relates to the way requestAnimationFrame acts when a tab is not visible. All the animations initiated when the tab is invisible “stack” and are not executed until the tab is brought back into focus. Then they all animate at warp speed! We’ve removed support for this API (which has no impact on the way you call jQuery’s animation features) and plan to incorporate it into a future version of jQuery.

I suggest that you update to a more recent version ... ie jQuery => 1.6.3

Comment: let me try to upgrade my jquery versin to 1.7.x .